# How to get datetime duplicate rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, datetime

Im trying to find duplicate `DATETIME` rows in a table,

My column has datetime values such as `2015-01-11 11:24:10.000`.

I must get the duplicates in `2015-01-11 11:24` type. Rest of it, not important. I can get the right value when I use `SELECT` with 'convert(nvarchar(16),column,121)', but when I put this in my code, I have to use 'group by' statement, so

My code is:

```
  SELECT ID,
         RECEIPT_BARCODE,
         convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121),
         PTYPE
    FROM TRANSACTION_HEADER
   WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '11.01.2015' AND '12.01.2015' 
GROUP BY ID,RECEIPT_BARCODE,convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121),PTYPE
  HAVING COUNT(convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121)) > 1
```

Since SQL forces me to use 'convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121)' in `GROUP BY` statement, I can't get the duplicate values.

Any idea for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ANSI SQL does not support convert. Please specify which dbms you are using, to get correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual *rows* that are duplicated, then use window functions instead:

```
SELECT  th.*, convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121)
FROM (SELECT th.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121)) as cnt
      FROM TRANSACTION_HEADER th
      WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '11.01.2015' AND '12.01.2015' 
     ) th
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ID,RECEIPT_BARCODE,convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121), PTYPE ,COUNT(*)
FROM    TRANSACTION_HEADER
WHERE   TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '11.01.2015' AND '12.01.2015' 
GROUP   ID,RECEIPT_BARCODE,convert(nvarchar(16),TRANS_DATE,121), PTYPE
HAVING   COUNT(*)>1;
```

I think you can use count(*) directly here.try the above one.

Comment: this one throw some exception but i just got the solution, thanks a lot for your consideration..

Comment: welcome mate , can you please tell me what it said ?

Comment: i modified yours and now im not getting exception. but i didnt get any result either :(